# SIPp returns error like "Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!"

Tags: sip, pcap, sipp

I am trying to play out some audio with rtp-nte dtmf to a cisco router. I
get the following error:

```
root@sipper:~# sipp -sf /root/aaravi-sip.xml -s 911 -i 10.106.106.72 -m 1 -pause_msg_ign -trace_msg -trace_shortmsg -f 1 -l 10000 -trace_err -trace_stat -trace_rtt -trace_logs -trace_screen -s 911 10.106.106.69
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
Ignoring non IP{4,6} packet!
```

I can see some discussions on the internet. But, no one seems to have posted
a solution. I could share the pcap file I was using.. Default pcaps and dtmf
samples work fine.!

Answer (score 0):

The type of pcap used in the SIPp should be 'Ethernet'. But when the packet is captured by tcpdump or wireshark, the packet type will 'Linux "cooked"'.

The type of pcap can be checked by the following command

```
root@sipper:~# file sample.pcap
sample.pcap: extended tcpdump capture file (little-endian) - version 2.4 (Linux "cooked", capture length 262144)
```

The linux cooked pcap can be converted to ethernet by using the following command

```
tcprewrite --dlt=enet -i sample.pcap -o sample-out.pcap
```